# Is it possible to use overflow-y and also use bootstrap 3.0 table-responsive class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table wrapped in a div with class table-responsive.

All works well and you can scroll up and down to view the entire table on small screens.

However my rows contain bootstrap dropdown menus which when opened are only partly visible. This is because the table-responsive div is clipping off the bottom of the menu.

It is possible to scroll down to view the entire menu but its not very neat or clear that thats what you have to do.

[screenshot http://www.bthodson.co.uk/screenshot.png](http://www.bthodson.co.uk/screenshot.png)

Ive experimented with overflow-y and z-index but nothing allows the menu to overflow the bottom of the div.

Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: Did you managed to get round this problem? I am having the same issue.